# Always prefix a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I know about the `prefix` argument we can pass while instantiating the form. My requirements are slightly different.

I have two forms like this

```
class TwitterForm(forms.Form):
    friends = forms.Charfield(...)

class FBForm(forms.Form):
    friends = forms.Charfield(...)
```

They will always be present together, which means I can guarantee that I will need to `prefix` them. Is there a way to add a prefix at class level rather than at the object creation time.

Answer (score 1):

Override `__init__()` and add the keyword argument before calling the parent's method.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a `Meta` attr I can set, seems like a common enough case.